# rails separate login for an api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I have a very simple api that is part of a rails app that requires logging in.

I just need a way to make the api part accessible with a simple form that allows the user to enter parameters like a key (just a simple one stored in the DB, no OAuth or anything), a userId to find and return a user via json, and maybe some other parameters like asking for their schedule.

How can I keep this seperate from the rest of the app, making it a public facing form that will grant access only to the api?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can auth the user by a token, i.e. if you are using devise, check the module :token_autenticable, and if you are not using devise, just add a field to the users and on create assign a unique string.

Then to serve the api app, you cannot hide that from the users, its a public resource, by using a token authentication you just make sure that common users doesn't get content that they are not allowed to see.

You can just create routes to your api, under a namespace, something like:

```
namespace :api do
  resources :schedules
end
```

so the requests of the api application will go to /api/schedules